# Module scanned but not got built

Tags: android, build, module

I put my module named "in32" into "external" directory and then ran "make" to build it. The following logs showed the "in32" had been scanned but I could not find any object or executable related to "in32" under the "out" directory.

```
including ./external/icu/Android.mk ...
including ./external/in32/Android.mk ...
including ./external/iproute2/Android.mk ...
```

Here is my Android.mk:

```
# Copyright 2006-2014 The Android Open Source Project

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= in32.c

#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog

LOCAL_MODULE := in32

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Werror

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Anything wrong?

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Found the cause. Has to append the module name to the PRODUCT_PACKAGES variable in the device.mk file as well.